# Pullback Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a bijection and $Y$ be a topological space.  Let $T_X \triangleq \left\{
f^{-1}[U]:\, U \mbox{ open in Y}
\right\}$.  Then is $T_X$ a topology on $X$ and if so, with it, is $X$ homeomorphic to $Y$?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: By definition $Y$ has the quotient topology wrt $T_X$. A bijective quotient map is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a topology:

1. $X,\emptyset \in T$, since $f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset, f^{-1}(Y)=X$.
2. If $(U_i)_{i\in I}\in T$, then $U_i=f^{-1}(V_i), V_i\in Y$ open. Note that $$\begin{align}\bigcup_i U_i&=\bigcup_i f^{-1}(V_i) \\ &= f^{-1}(\bigcup_i V_i) \\ &=f^{-1}(V),\end{align}$$ where $V=\bigcup_i V_i$ is open since $Y$ is a topological space, and so the union is also open.
3. If $U_1,U_2\in T$, then $U_1=f^{-1}(V_1), U_2=f^{-1}(V_2)$, and so $f^{-1}(V_1) \cap f^{-1}(V_2)= f^{-1}(V_1\cap V_2)=f^{-1}(V)$, where $V=V_1\cap V_2$  is open (from the definition of topology), and so the finite intersection is open.

$f$ is also a homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$. It is a bijection by definition. It is also continuous, since the topology is defined so that the preimage of an open set is open (and only it). It is also an open map, since again, by the definition of the topology on $X$, the image of an open set is open. So overall, it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Jynx!  I think we posted at the same time .

Answer (score 1):

Since $\bigcup_{i \in I} f^{-1}[U_i] = f^{-1}[\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i] $, then the arbitrary union of open sets is open in $T_X$.  Likewise, $\bigcap_{i=1}^N f^{-1}[U_i] = f^{-1}[\bigcap_{i=1}^N U_i] $ for every $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ so finite-interesctions play nice.
Since $f$ is a bijection then $X = f^{-1}[Y]$ so **[we win!](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02G7)**

Finally, since $f$ is a bijection then the statements hold for it and its inverse and so open sets map to and from open sets between these two spaces.  So it's a homeomorphism.